# Emacs: how to break out of ido minibuffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm generally using `ido-switch-buffer`, but sometimes when there are too many candidates,
`helm-buffers-list` is preferable. But it's a hassle to break out of ido,
call helm and re-enter the lost information.

So I wrote this code, that re-uses information entered in ido directly in helm:

```
(require 'helm-buffers)
(defun switch-to-helm-buffers-list ()
  "Emulate `helm-buffers-list' call with ido contents as initial input."
  (interactive)
  (let ((str (minibuffer-contents-no-properties)))
    (helm :sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                     helm-source-ido-virtual-buffers
                     helm-source-buffer-not-found)
          :buffer "*helm buffers*"
          :keymap helm-buffer-map
          :truncate-lines t
          :input str)
    ;; (ido-exit-minibuffer)
    ))

(add-hook
 'ido-setup-hook
 (lambda()
   (define-key ido-buffer-completion-map "\C-i"
     'switch-to-helm-buffers-list)))
```

One problem is that ido is left to linger in the minibuffer.
When I add a call `ido-exit-minibuffer` before `helm`, it's not called.
And when I add it after, it resets the window configuration.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It could just be me, but calling `ido-exit-minibuffer` in a recursive minibuffer does nothing.

Comment: If you don't need recursive edit to be active, then perhaps `(top-level)` might do the trick:  "*Exit all recursive editing levels. This also exits all active minibuffers.*"?  To just exit one level of recursive edit, perhaps something like this: `(if (> (recursion-depth) 0) (throw 'exit nil))`

Comment: just a thought, because lingering minibuffers brings back some memories, but do you have popwin installed?

Comment: @nymo, I've installed it, doesn't help.

Comment: Oh i meant that it caused my minibuffer to linger when installed.  Sorry, remove it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165658/1937596

---

First, I patch your function a little.

```
(require 'helm-buffers)
(defun switch-to-helm-buffers-list ()
  "Emulate `helm-buffers-list' call with ido contents as initial input."
  (interactive)
  (let ((str ido-text))
    (helm :sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                     helm-source-ido-virtual-buffers
                     helm-source-buffer-not-found)
          :buffer "*helm buffers*"
          :keymap helm-buffer-map
          :truncate-lines t
          :input str)
    ))
```

My recipe patches the body of function `ido-buffer-internal` (internal for `ido-switch-buffer`) too.
You have to execute this code once.

```
(eval
 (read
  (replace-regexp-in-string
   "cond"
   "cond ((eq ido-exit 'eab-ido-helm) (call-interactively 'switch-to-helm-buffers-list)) "
   (save-window-excursion
     (find-function-do-it 'ido-buffer-internal nil 'switch-to-buffer)
     (let ((bgn (point)))
       (forward-sexp)
       (let ((end (point)))
     (buffer-substring-no-properties bgn end)))))))
```

And I add one auxiliary function.

```
(defun eab/ido-helm ()
  (interactive)
  (setq ido-exit 'eab-ido-helm)
  (exit-minibuffer))
```

Note, I use `eab/ido-helm` instead of `switch-to-helm-buffers-list` in `define-key`.

```
(add-hook
 'ido-setup-hook
 (lambda()
   (define-key ido-buffer-completion-map "\C-i"
     'eab/ido-helm)))
```

Comment: I reluctantly patched `ido-buffer-internal`, (a simple diff would be better btw:),
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried again and it works. It was a key binding issue I think.
I'll see if it's possible to avoid patching `ido-buffer-internal`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with. No patching required.

```
(define-key ido-buffer-completion-map "\C-i" 'ido-buffer-helm)

(defvar ibh-initial nil)

(defun ibh-hook ()
  (when ibh-initial
    (let ((str ibh-initial))
      (setq ibh-initial)
      (helm :sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                       helm-source-ido-virtual-buffers
                       helm-source-buffer-not-found)
            :buffer "*helm buffers*"
            :keymap helm-buffer-map
            :truncate-lines t
            :input str)))
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'ibh-hook))

(require 'delsel)

(defun ido-buffer-helm ()
  (interactive)
  (setq ibh-initial ido-text)
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'ibh-hook)
  (minibuffer-keyboard-quit))
```

Comment: There is one problem: it puts current ido candidate buffer to selected window before executing `ido-buffer-helm`.

Comment: Indeed it does. I should fix that.

Comment: Found this: try `(minibuffer-keyboard-quit)` instead of `(exit-minibuffer)` in `ido-buffer-helm`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. If you do elisp coding, check out https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy.
I just pushed a commit there that shows arguments and documentation inline.